# Como recorrer a columna de un datagridview c# foreach

Tags: c#, visual-studio, foreach

Necesito ayuda como hacer esto
Necesito recorrer una columna ( cantidad ) del datagridview cuando la cantidad llegue a 0 para que no me deje insertar productos que no tienen existencia y me deje un mensaje que esta no hay existencias  (no hay productos )
Alguna idea ?

Comment: y que probaste hasta el momento? un mensaje en donde? de que cantidad hablas?

Comment: Lo que dices, no tiene mucha lógica de la manera que lo expresas pero mira aqui un ejemplo de guia: `foreach (DataGridViewRow row in tuDataGridView.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt16(tuDataGridView.Rows[row.Index].Cells["cantidad"].Value == 0) 
            {
                 MessageBox.Show("No tiene existencia."); return;
            }
        }`

Answer (score -1):

Este codigo es la respuesta a tu problema. :)
de nada.
PDTA: lo que hace esto es, mientras tenga datos recorrer en `DataGidView`, cuando deje de tener datos dejara de leerlo para no producir el error que te sale.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dtv in this.tuDataGridView.Rows){
                        //aqui pones tu codigo
}
```